# How can you wrap an HTML element with a complex structure?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html element and I need to wrap it with the following structure:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="somewrapper">
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="bar">
            <div class="foobar1"></div>
            <div class="foobar2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="anotherclass"></div>
        <div class="yetanotherclass">
            <!-- the element to be wrapped should go here -->
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="anotherwrapper">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

My HTML element existing on the page should be wrapped by the above structure and end up in `.yetanotherclass`.

I have looked into all of the variations of jQuery's `wrap()` function, but it doesn't seem support this sort of requirement (correct me if I'm wrong).

[edit]

The block of HTML provided above is constructed via javascript and is not available on the page (it is, at this point, held in a variable).  Also, there are events bound to the html element to be wrapped and it would be nice if I didn't have to rebind.. I am thinking maybe an append / copy / remove might work but it seems a little messy.

Comment: use `$element.before('.yetanotherclass .clearfix')`?

Comment: That would work, but the html structure I provided does not exist on the page yet.

Comment: you could use the above line immediately after you put the html structure on the page.

Comment: .wrap doesn't support this, you'll have to append the new html, then move the element to it's new location.

Comment: Yeah.. I just edited my question. I was hoping there might be a better way. =[  Thanks

Comment: @KennyThompson: I’m pretty sure that `jQuery.wrap()` removes the element to be wrapped, then re-appends it to whatever you’re wrapping it with, so you’re basically doing the same thing.

Comment: Just appending it keeps the event handlers and associated data as it's only moved in the DOM, as long as the template is appended first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MjS6P/1/

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `.prepend()`

```
$('.yetanotherclass').prepend('<div id="yournewelement">some html</div>');
```

if you have html code in javascript you can store it inside a var and prepend that element like this:

```
var html = '<div id="yournewelement">some html</div>';
$('.yetanotherclass').prepend(html);
```

**UPDATE**

try to wrap your code in this way:

```
$('#elementtobewrapped').nextUntil('.clearfix').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="yetanotherclass" />');
```

Comment: $('.yetanotherclass') doesn't exist yet.  I made an edit to the post.  Thanks!

Comment: update my answer, you need to use an id or a selector to the code that you want to wrap @KennyThompson

Answer (score 1):

Grab your template from string ( or jQuery object), or using script tag to hold it as template, or from container in page.

Wrap your template html in `$()`

```
var template=/* source html*/
var $template=$(template)
```

Then insert the html you want.

```
$template.find('.yetanotherclass').html( /* source of content*/)
$('#someElement').append($template)
```

Comment: This is sounding more like a solution.  I am worried I will lose any events bound to the 'source of content'

Comment: will most likely lose events

Answer (score 0):

My move would be to store the wrapper template in the DOM (as a hidden field or a non-standard script tag) and then clone it when you need to use it. That way you don't have to create this giant HTML element in your JS file.

That said, you can definitely create each div and append/perpend them in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of is something like this..

Element

```
<button>Button</button>
```

Script

```
$('button').replaceWith($('<div class="someclass"><div class="somewrapper">' +
    '<div class="foo"></div><div class="bar"><div class="foobar1"></div>' +
    '<div class="foobar2"></div></div><div class="anotherclass"></div>' +
    '<div class="yetanotherclass">' + $('button')[0].outerHTML + '<div class="clearfix"></div></div>' +
    '<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="anotherwrapper"><div class="clearfix"></div></div>' +
    '<div class="clearfix"></div></div>'));
```